# What does the :link do in CSS?

Tags: html, css

So while having an a tag with the class btn I can style it by using .btn in my CSS. However some say it's a better practice to style your button with `.btn:link` instead of just `.btn`. Using `:hover` makes a clear difference on the output. But I was wondering what exactly the difference is between styling with or without `:link`

```css
.btn:link {
  background-color: #67c5fc;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #0082ce;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn2 {
  background-color: #48c964;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.btn2:hover {
  background-color: #2eaa49;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Button-with-:link</a>
<a href="#" class="btn2">Button-without-:link</a>
```

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link) might hold some info regarding that.

Comment: [https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_link.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_link.asp) see this link for more info about :link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is explain:

> The :link CSS pseudo-class represents an element that has not yet been
>   visited. It matches every unvisited `<a>`, `<area>`, or `<link>` element
>   that has an `href` attribute.

**By default, most browsers apply a special color value to visited links. 
When you use `:link` you can declare new style instead the default definition**

Learn more here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link

Answer (score 0):

The `:link` selector is used to select unvisited links.

It is the opposite of the `:visited` selector.